# how to use getStaticProps to fetch first ten blog posts with fallback

Tags: next.js

I have a big blog with more than thousand posts in Next.js, and i have used getStaticProps to fetch mdx post data. but by growing of post quantity, it's take more time to build the websites for all the post page.

my problem is i dont want to use getServerProps, and find the solution fallback (true or blocking) would be great for rendering my first 50 posts, WITHOUT LISTEING ALL 50 paths in getStaticPath, instead take these 50 paths as object, but i always goes wrong with that object.

anyone can make a coding sample,  thanks.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

const preRenderingPosts = posts.slice(0,50).data.slug  // something like this, but always wrong

  const paths = postFilePaths
    .map((path) => path.replace(/\.mdx?$/, ""))
    .map((slug) => ({ params: { slug } }));
  return {
    paths: preRenderingPosts
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects that includes the slug of the first 50 posts in this way:

```
const preRenderingPosts = posts.slice(0,50).map(post => ({ slug: post.data.slug }));
```